# Выполнять php процесс в фоне

Tags: php, очередь

Есть функция отправки sms уведомления на php, она выполняется около 3х секунд, иногда приходится делать рассылку сразу на несколько номеров, ожидание увеличивается пропорционально.

Нужно как-то вывести выполнение этой задачи в фон, чтоб не заставлять пользователя ждать. Результат выполнения логируется отдельно, поэтому процесс можно бросить и забыть, никакой результат не нужен для вывода.

Процесс представляет собой функцию на php с двумя передаваемыми параметрами.

Мне кажется, чт овсе решения с серверами очередей - слишком избыточны, т.к. мне не нужны очереди, планировщики и даже не нужно сохранение результата выполнения

Comment: можно сделать асинхронный http запрос в свой же api, вызвать шелл-скрипт без ожидания результата (> /dev/null 2>&1), можно попробовать просто зафлашить ответ пользователю и работать дальше. Но лучше всего, конечно, делегировать такую задачу диспетчеру очередей.

Comment: добавляйте отправляемые данные в БД. после сохранения пользователь может спокойно покинуть страницу. Потом с помощью cron запускайте по расписанию скрипт который будет брать эти данные и отправлять куда надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел для себя 2 решения:

1. `exec("/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/smssend.php ".$telnum." ".$text."> /dev/null 2>&1");`
   Как было подсказано в комментариях, выношу свою функцию в отдельный файл, который принимает 2 параметра и бросаю его выполнение на произвол судьбы
   Помимо команды на выполнение php файла я передаю еще 2 параметра через пробел, которые считываются в исполняемом файле как

   $telnum=$argv[1];
   $text=$argv[2];
2. Им я в итоге и воспользовался - сервер очередей, все не так сложно оказалось, как я думал, поставил gearman, в нем doBackground - отправляю процесс с параметрами в очередь и workerом очередь обрабатывается

Comment: В первом варианте главное не забыть `escapeshellarg`